# SendGrid template not respecting outlook beta in Mac

Tags: html-email, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I've been trying to modify my template but I'm running into some issues when it comes to using columns on SendGrid. The main issue is when the email when a user views an email from a mac with outlook desktop in beta.

Everything works fine in terms of windows / mobile devices. I've attempted a number of things including remove all % based widths, removed padding and replaced one table padding to no avail.

Mac based outlook beta:
[Mac Outlook Beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwAhu.png)
Vs. Windows based outlook beta
[Outlook Windows Beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiA0o.png)
Vs. SendGrid
[SendGrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hGtb.png)

Below is a snipper of the code I'm using that contains the issues. I did revert all the widths % back as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html data-editor-version="2" class="sg-campaigns" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <!--[if !mso]><!-->
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
      <!--<![endif]-->
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG/>
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml>
      <![endif]-->
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {width: 600px;margin: 0 auto;}
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    table, td {mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;}
    img {-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
      <style type="text/css">
    body, p, div {
      font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    body {
      color: #000000;
    }
    body a {
      color: #1188E6;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    table.wrapper {
      width:100% !important;
      table-layout: fixed;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    img.max-width {
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
    .column.of-2 {
      width: 50%;
    }
    .column.of-3 {
      width: 33.333%;
    }
    .column.of-4 {
      width: 25%;
    }
    ul ul ul ul  {
      list-style-type: disc !important;
    }
    ol ol {
      list-style-type: lower-roman !important;
    }
    ol ol ol {
      list-style-type: lower-latin !important;
    }
    ol ol ol ol {
      list-style-type: decimal !important;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
      .preheader .rightColumnContent,
      .footer .rightColumnContent {
        text-align: left !important;
      }
      .preheader .rightColumnContent div,
      .preheader .rightColumnContent span,
      .footer .rightColumnContent div,
      .footer .rightColumnContent span {
        text-align: left !important;
      }
      .preheader .rightColumnContent,
      .preheader .leftColumnContent {
        font-size: 80% !important;
        padding: 5px 0;
      }
      table.wrapper-mobile {
        width: 100% !important;
        table-layout: fixed;
      }
      img.max-width {
        height: auto !important;
        max-width: 100% !important;
      }
      a.bulletproof-button {
        display: block !important;
        width: auto !important;
        font-size: 80%;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
      }
      .columns {
        width: 100% !important;
      }
      .column {
        display: block !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
        margin-right: 0 !important;
      }
      .social-icon-column {
        display: inline-block !important;
      }
    }
  </style>
    <style>
      @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
        table\0 {
          width: 480px !important;
          }
      }
    </style>
      <!--user entered Head Start--><!--End Head user entered-->
    </head>
    <body>
      <center class="wrapper" data-link-color="#1188E6" data-body-style="font-size:14px; font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <div class="webkit">
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
              <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%">
                <table width="100%" role="content-container" class="outer" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="100%">
                      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <!--[if mso]>
    <center>
    <table><tr><td width="600">
  <![endif]-->
                                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:100%; max-width:600px;" align="center">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td role="modules-container" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; color:#000000; text-align:left;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" align="left"><table class="module preheader preheader-hide" role="module" data-type="preheader" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none !important; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; color: transparent; height: 0; width: 0;">
    <tr>
      <td role="module-content">
        <p></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" role="module" data-type="columns" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" data-distribution="1,1">
    <tbody>
      <tr role="module-content">
        <td height="100%" valign="top"><table width="290" style="width:290px; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; margin:0px 10px 0px 0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" border="0" bgcolor="" class="column column-0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-spacing:0;"><table class="wrapper" role="module" data-type="image" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-muid="bb6006b4-bbf0-49b5-be5a-52302ee423ec">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-size:6px; line-height:10px; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;" valign="top" align="center">
          <img class="max-width" border="0" style="display:block; color:#000000; text-decoration:none; font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; max-width:100% !important; width:100%; height:auto !important;" width="290" alt="" data-proportionally-constrained="true" data-responsive="true" src="http://cdn.mcauto-images-production.sendgrid.net/ccd9b4a97697bd64/4cc5315b-84ba-42bb-ad92-425f4528bb6b/7815x3217.png">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table><table width="290" style="width:290px; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; margin:0px 0px 0px 10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" border="0" bgcolor="" class="column column-1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:0px;margin:0px;border-spacing:0;"><table class="module" role="module" data-type="text" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-muid="c685a561-dc07-4dda-a2a9-c6d64e44c776" data-mc-module-version="2019-10-22">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="padding:18px 0px 18px 0px; line-height:22px; text-align:inherit;" height="100%" valign="top" bgcolor="" role="module-content"><div><div style="font-family: inherit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt elementum sem non luctus.</div><div></div></div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table><div data-role="module-unsubscribe" class="module" role="module" data-type="unsubscribe" style="color:#444444; font-size:12px; line-height:20px; padding:16px 16px 16px 16px; text-align:Center;" data-muid="4e838cf3-9892-4a6d-94d6-170e474d21e5"><div class="Unsubscribe--addressLine"></div><p style="font-size:12px; line-height:20px;"><a target="_blank" class="Unsubscribe--unsubscribeLink zzzzzzz" href="{{{unsubscribe}}}" style="">Unsubscribe</a> - <a href="{{{unsubscribe_preferences}}}" target="_blank" class="Unsubscribe--unsubscribePreferences" style="">Unsubscribe Preferences</a></p></div></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!--[if mso]>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </table>
                            </center>
                            <![endif]-->
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </center>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing and I'm hoping someone may be able to help in regards to this issue.

I'm hoping someone may have the key to the answer I'm missing.

Attempted to remove width %'s, attempted to remove all padding and replace with cellpadding / other, attempted to remove all margins to no avail

Comment: Why do you think this is an issue with SendGrid? I assume you also used SendGrid to send the emails shown on Windows and the mobile device, right? I'd assume the problem is caused that Outlook for Mac uses another rendering engine and therefore prints the HTML differently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML Email issue in Outlook MacOs Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75616946/html-email-issue-in-outlook-macos-devices)